[VirtualBox Error adding a existing VM "VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"
I've added an existing VM to my new Virtual Box installation, but when I started my VM this error appears on the side screen:

"VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Any sugestions?

